# JavaScript: Getting two different value of dropdownlist selected index value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one dropdown list in my pgae. when I alert two continues times value of dropdown selected index I get two different value. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// here code for getting data from server to bind dropdown
DoAjaxCall("?method=getDataForDDL&callbackmethod=BindDDL")

// after binding data to dropdown I wrote following two alert
alert(document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex); //this alert -1
alert(document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex); // this alert 0
alert(document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex); // this alert 0
}
function BindDDL(data, msg) {// this function is called automatically after   successfull AJAX call 
    var tbldata = eval('(' + data.toString() + ')'); //convert JSON data to Javascript Object
    var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlState");
    for (var i = 0; i < tbldata.Table.length; i++) {
        ddl.options[ddl.length] = new Option(tbldata.Table[i][1], tbldata.Table[i][0]);
    }
}
function DoAjaxCall(parameter){
 //code for getting data from server by "POST" method
 //After this function BindDDL is called which is call back function.
 }
```

Comment: If you can not get my question please tell me.

Comment: Can't replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/xbZbA/1/ I'm guessing there is another problem with your code that you aren't showing.

Comment: @Anil Please share the commented code. I tried the same i.e. alert two  times but i am getting correct answer.

Comment: I can replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/xbZbA/3/ ; It seems when your first call is happening, the dropdown has not yet been bound (no options). You are not sharing the relevant code.

Comment: ideally your `alert(document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex);` should be after `BindDDL`. this is ajax, wherever you are using the dropdown, you must call that as a last line in `BindDDL`.

Comment: @abhitalks BindDDL is called before                       alert(document.getElementById("ddlState").selectedIndex); statement.
BindDDL is callback function of DoAjaxCall function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX request are asynchronous, so you can't put your selected index checking code after the AJAX call; you have to put it in the callback to the AJAX request.  Therefore, it's possible the first time you get -1, the list hasn't been populated with any data, but the second time it is.

Comment: you mean I have to put alert in BindDDL function.

Comment: Yes, put that functionality there.

Comment: Thanks .... "AJAX request are asynchronous" this sentence solved my problem and understand what that mean.